# Rankx showing wrong values in visual when filtering for only one organisation

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have been trying to rank provider using Rankx  but it is showing incorrect values for some of the filter values.

Currently, I have selected the provider name as Newman in the card and used the following code to calculate the rank and average positivity measure

```
Rank = RANKX(ALL('All subjects'[provider name]), [Average Positvity Measure (%)], , DESC)
```

```
Average Positivity % = AVERAGE('TableName'[Positivity Measure])
```

As shown in the image below i am getting incorrect rank in card as compared to matrix
[Sample error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJHIK.png)

I tried using different visual if rankx doesnot work with card visual, Checked filter interactions and data types of columns

Answer (score 0):

If i did understand correctly you want to show the rank of a selected provider in the card, to do so you need to use [SELECTEDVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function) function, you new measure will be like:

```
selected_rank = CALCULATE([rank], 'All subjects'[provider name] = SELECTEDVALUE('All subjects'[provider name])
```